# Bootstrap ToggleButton menu like Facebook

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, toggle

Please I need to replicate in bootstrap the following behavior:
In facebook mobile, when you click "v" in any post a full width bottom menu is open (one of the items of menu is Report)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you want but I have a panel with glyphicon icon (^) and when you click the panel hides here is the exaple code:

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Create Alert</h4>
             <span class="btn btn-xs btnAgregar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#formulario"></span>
         </div>

     <div id="formulario" class="collapse in">
         <div class="panel-body">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class=" form-group col-md-2">
                    <label class="control-label">ID:</label>
                    <input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />
        </div>
         <div class=" form-group col-md-2">
          <label class="control-label">Panel Collapse Example</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
     .btnAgregar:after {
           font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
           content: "\e113";
      }

      .btnAgregar.collapsed:after {
           content: "\e114";
       }
```

I uploaded the example here https://jsfiddle.net/uhusp0uy/
If you want to show the panel hiden from the beginning just change the class="collapse in" to class="collapse"